# How to add attribute option underneath title on Product_add Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want attribute option underneath title on Product_add

Here I am try some code but it is not working properly

Then here selected option directly store in attribute table

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title','wp_after_title_fields_34490557');

function wp_after_title_fields_34490557($post) {
  if($post->post_type == 'product') {
    echo 'City &nbsp';
    echo '<select name="product_city">';
    echo '<option value="city">bangalore</option>';
    echo '<option value="city">chennai</option>';
    echo '</select>';
  }
}
```

Comment: DaveyDaveDave thanks

Comment: Can you re-phrase this? I don't understand what you are asking. What isn't working?

Comment: i want to define a custom attribute (constant) on every new product in woocommerce    @helgatheviking